# Run custom python code on ROS docker container

Tags: python, docker-compose, ros

I'm beginner with ROS, and I'm trying to run some listener/talker node running a really simple code in python, using ROS on a Docker container.

I'm following the guide described in:
https://hub.docker.com/_/ros

I got this structure:

```
./
    Dockerfile
    docker-compose.yml
    ./teste/
            listener.py
```

My current goal is to pass the listener.py code and run in a "listener" node, running as a service container.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ros:foxy        
 # install ros package 
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
              ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-demo-nodes-cpp \
              ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-demo-nodes-py && \
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
        
# launch ros package

CMD ["ros2", "launch", "demo_nodes_cpp", "talker_listener.launch.py"]
```

My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
version: '3'

services:
  talker:
    build: ./
    command: ros2 run demo_nodes_py talker

  listener:
    build: ./
    environment:
      - "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
    volumes:
      - ./teste:/teste
    command: ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener

volumes:
  teste:
```

With this default code, the two services runs the listener/talker from the original ros examples, but i want to run my own python code. How do i do that? Even that the listener service can access listener.py code (via ./teste) if i open an shell and try to execute it, the ros2 run command is not recognized.

What am i doing wrong? Am i supposed to do something before to make my python code work on ros2? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Edit: ros2 command is not recognized if i open a shell terminal, but the by the cmd command on the Dockerfile, with the talker_listener.launch.py code, it works.

Edit2: i managed to run the setup.sh via "/bin/bash source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash". Even so, i can't run the ros2 commands. I used "python3 /teste/listener.py", but then i got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospy'
```

How is that possible, if when i run the default command option (ros2 run demo_nodes_py listener, via Dockerfile) and it works?